# Input of 2 strings separated by a space in c

Tags: c, string

I am getting input with the format:

```
<string 1> <string 2>
```

For example, "hello world".

I have a length limit for both strings. Is there a quick way to put the strings in separate variables?

At the end I am comparing `string 1` with some other string, and until it matches I keep getting more strings (with the same format) from the user.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, with `scanf("%s%s", string1, string2);` But you  should also restrict the input length.

Comment: Is input as lines (2 words per line), or just words split to lines arbitrarily? That is, if there are 3 words in one line and 1 more in next line, what should happen? Or can you just assume input is in valid format (whatever it is)?

Comment: @hyde This is the only input format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept the input from the user by formatting `scanf()` function as shown:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(void) {
    char str1[MAX], str2[MAX];

    printf("Enter two words separated by spaces: ");
    scanf("%s %s", str1, str2); // here's the main stuff

    printf("Variable 1 now contains: %s\n", str1);
    printf("Variable 2 contains: %s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

**A sample output:**

```
Enter two words separated by spaces: Hello World
Variable 1 now contains: Hello
Variable 2 contains: World
```